# proftpd, limit STOR (appending file) to only fresh files

Tags: time, upload, proftpd, limitations

I'm trying configure uploading file in proftpd.
In docs there is option: AllowStoreRestart on/off.
It controlls continue uploading is permitted or denied.
Is it possible permit store restart (REST+STOR ftp protocol) but based by how old is file?

Intention is restart storing only for fresh file. Unfortunately I nowhere found adequate limit configuration.

Workaround for this scenario is script that will observe ftp log, and revoke file modification if it is old enough.

Answer (score 0):

No, allowing resuming upload based on age/last-modified-timestamp of the destination file not currently a supported feature in ProFTPD.